# Gradient of a composite function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $ \mathbf{ G}: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R^2 $ be given by $G(x,y)=(cos(x-y),sin(x+y)) $

Assume that $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ is differentiable, with gradient $\nabla f(0,1) = (2,3)$ in $(0,1)$. Let $h: \Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ be given by $h(x)=f(\mathbf{G}(\mathbf{x}))$ for all $x$.

What is the gradient $\nabla h( \frac{\pi}{2},0 )$ of $h$ in $(\frac{\pi}{2},0)$?

Comment: hint: use the chain rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $G(\pi/2,0)=(0,1)$ you get:
$$
 \nabla h = D f(0,1)\cdot DG(\pi/2,0)
$$
which is a $1\times 2$ times $2\times 2$ matrix multiplication.